# Apple in app purchase verify receipt returning xml

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

All of sudden https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt  is now returning an xml response intermittently.  Sandbox mode isn't doing this.  It looks like api docs a plist wsdl if you will.  Anyone else seeing responses like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Apple WebObjects
Content-Length: 5782
x-apple-jingle-correlation-key: JI6NEX6V3DMRO
pod: 51
x-apple-orig-url-path: /verifyReceipt
x-apple-request-store-front: <null>
x-apple-translated-wo-url: /verifyReceipt
x-set-apple-store-front: 143441-1,8
x-apple-application-site: ST11
edge-control: no-store, cache-maxage=0
Set-Cookie: Pod=51; version="1"; expires=Fri, 19-Apr-2013 23:38:52 GMT; path=/;            domain=.apple.com, mzf_in=510546; version="1"; path=/WebObjects; domain=.apple.com; secure, mzf_odc=ST1; version="1"; expires=Wed, 20-Mar-2013 00:08:52 GMT; path=/WebObjects; domain=.apple.com, mzf_dr=0; version="1"; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/WebObjects; domain=.apple.com
 apple-timing-app: 5 ms
 Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0
 x-apple-asset-version: 0
 Expires: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 23:38:52 GMT
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
 x-apple-lokamai-no-cache: true
 x-apple-date-generated: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 23:38:52 GMT
 x-apple-application-instance: 510546
 Pragma: no-cache
 x-webobjects-loadaverage: 30
 Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 23:38:52 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<Document xmlns="http://www.apple.com/itms/">

<Protocol>
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>jingleDocType</key><string>initiateSecureSessionSuccess</string>
            <key>jingleAction</key><string>initiateSecureSession</string>
            <key>urlBag</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>authenticateAccount</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/authenticate</string>
<key>iPhoneActivation</key><string>https://albert.apple.com/verifyReceipt/ALActivation.woa/wa/iPhoneRegistration</string>
<key>device-activation</key><string>https://albert.apple.com/verifyReceipt/ALActivation.woa/wa/deviceActivation</string>
<key>carrierDeviceInfo</key><string>https://albert.apple.com/verifyReceipt/ALActivation.woa/wa/carrierDeviceInfo</string>
<key>authorizeMachine</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/authorizeMachine</string>
<key>buyProduct</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/buyProduct</string>
<key>buyCart</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/buyCart</string>
<key>deauthorizeMachine</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/deauthorizeMachine</string>
<key>machineAuthorizationInfo</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFastFinance.woa/wa/machineAuthorizationInfo</string>
<key>modifyAccount</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/accountSummary</string>
<key>pendingSongs</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/pendingSongs</string>
<key>signup</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/signupWizard</string>
<key>songDownloadDone</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFastFinance.woa/wa/songDownloadDone</string>
<key>forgottenPassword</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/iForgot</string>
<key>myInfo</key><string>https://appleid.apple.com/</string>
<key>noAOLAccounts</key><false/>
<key>logout</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/logout</string>
<key>addToCart</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/addToCart</string>
<key>removeFromCart</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/removeFromCart</string>
<key>shoppingCart</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/shoppingCart</string>
<key>bcURLs</key><array><string>http://.phobos.apple.com</string><string>http://www.atdmt.com</string></array>
<key>reportPodcast</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/reportPodcast</string>
<key>check-download-queue</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/checkDownloadQueue</string>
<key>set-auto-download</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/setAutoDownload</string>
<key>new-ipod-user</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/iPodRegistration</string>
<key>new-tv-user</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/iTVRegistration</string>
<key>md5-mismatch</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/md5Mismatch</string>
<key>report-error</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/reportErrorFromClient</string>
<key>updateAsset</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/updateAsset</string>
<key>create-token</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/createToken</string>
<key>create-session</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/createSession</string>

    <key>digital-copy</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/digitalCopyWizard</string>

<key>p2-redemption</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/p2RedeemCode</string>
<key>p2-redeem-service-terms-url</key><string>http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/ww/</string>
<key>pendingApps</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/pendingApps</string>
<key>checkAppQueue</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/checkAppDownloadQueue</string>
<key>marketing-action</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/viewMarketingPage</string>      


  <key>mint-offers</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/presentOffers</string>
  <key>mint-account</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/accountSummary</string>
  <key>mint-account-fragment</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/accountSummaryFragment</string>



<key>uploadPublishedPlaylist</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/uploadPublishedPlayList</string>
<key>giftPlaylist</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard</string>
<key>give-playlist</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard</string>



  <key>adopt-product</key><string>https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/MZFinance.woa/wa/adoptProduct</string>



            </dict>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</Protocol>

</Document>
```

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Maybe it's a bug that was just deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's official answer

> A technical issue occurred that has now been resolved- we apologize for the inconvenience. Further details cannot be provided at this time.

Appears to be working fine today, must have been a bad deploy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the production verifyReceipt service.

File a DTS ticket to let them know about the issue.  I'm certain they're working on it right now.

My server records show that the number of requests returning XML has gone down over the past hour.